# posgresql-libreoffice(base): how to connect heroku database to libreoffice base

Tags: postgresql, heroku, libreoffice, heroku-postgres, libreoffice-base

I want to use Heroku PostgreSQL database through my LibreOffice Base, I'm a newbie at this, can't find any good articles online, Is it even possible, if yes, how? My goal is to administer my local database online.

Comment: PostgreSQL with Base is a popular combination, and it works well.  I am not familiar with Heroku, so I cannot answer about that part of it.